# mysql ssl spring boot 2

Tags: openssl, google-cloud-platform, jks

Hi I've got a mysql server and a kubernetes spring boot 2 web service running in gcloud. So the issue is that I don't know how to convert my client-key.pem into a jks file. Ive already converted client-key.pem file into jks file with the following command.

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file client-cert.pem -keystore client-cert.jks
```

The same command gives me an error when I'm using on the key.pem, keytool error:`java.lang.exception: input not an x.509 certificate.` 
 The pem files are fine(generated by Google cloud console), works perfectly from mysql workbench. Any help appriacited thx!

Answer (score 1):

converting from `PEM` to `Java KeyStore` is a little complicated ...

a) convert the certificate from `PEM` to `PKCS12`:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out client-cert.pkcs12 -in client-cert.pem
```

b) create and then empty a truststore `KS`:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias client -keystore truststore.ks
keytool -delete -alias client -keystore truststore.ks
```

c) import the `CA` into the truststore `KS`:

```
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias client-ca -file client-cert.pem -keystore truststore.ks
```

d) create and then empty a `Java KeyStore`:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias client -keystore keystore.ks
keytool -delete -alias client -keystore keystore.ks
```

e) import the `PKCS12` into the empty `Java KeyStore`:

```
keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore client-cert.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore.ks -deststoretype JKS
```

Answer (score 1):

Martin Zeitler and one of my colleague pointed me to the right direction. Still it's not the perfect answer so I will answer my question.
You get 3 files from google cloud the **client.cert.pem**, **client-key.pem** and **server-ca.pem**.
Turns out you don't need the **server-ca.pem** file to connect to the server from mysql workbench, but you need it, if you want to connect to the server from java.
First openssl, install it with the following command on probably any distro.

**sudo apt install openssl -y**

After that you type these commands:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out merged.pkcs12 -in client-cert.pem -inkey client-key.pem -certfile server-ca.pem
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias client -keystore truststore.jks
keytool -delete -alias client -keystore truststore.jks
keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias server-ca -file server-ca.pem -keystore truststore.jks
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias client -keystore keystore.jks
keytool -delete -alias client -keystore keystore.jks
keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore merged.pkcs12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -destkeystore JKS
```

Set these JDBC parameters:

```
verifyServerCertificate=true
useSSL=true
requireSSL=true
clientCertificateKeyStorePassword=password
clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl=keystore.jks
trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=password
trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=truststore.jks
```

And that's it folks!